# Emulator error : x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration

Tags: android-studio

This error happened under Android studio 3.4. I'm using `Windows 10`. I didn't find any way to fix it on the other threads asking the same question.

Especially, I've installed Intel `HAXM` manually, my BIOS settings are allowing virtualization, it can't be a problem involving my anti-virus as I tried to run my project while it was disabled, I've also rebuild my project each time.

What am I missing? Thanks already to all those who will answer me.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I had to go change the advanced settings of the emulated software, changing the "graphics" value by "software ..." instead of "hardware ...".